# Can't boot phone or access recovery mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, custom-roms, boot, unbricking

I tried updating a custom ROM on my Samsung Galaxy S: Semaphore Version 9 (Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean). The update was successful except that it produced an error after completion saying the process "android.process.acore" has stopped.

So I had to restore to the previous version through recovery mode. However after the the applications were calibrated and the phone was supposed to start, it did not! The boot animation kept on going. I tried restoring my phone to the back up that I had created when I was using ICS 4.0.4, but I realized that I had deleted the ZIP file of the ICS version.

Now when my phone powers on, it only displays the picture of the kernel version of the back up version of ICS.

I cannot access recovery mode. I tried to hard reset as well, as described in one of the links, but that didn't work either. However, The download mode works fine.

Is there anyway I can make my phone work?

Comment: If download-mode still works, you can flash a ROM via [Odin](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info) (Windows only) or [Heimdall](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/heimdall/info) (cross-platform).

Comment: Does your phone have root?